# How to write to stderr in Nim?

Tags: nim-lang

I know there is `echo`, which writes to stdout. Is it possible to redirect `echo` to stderr, or is there another way to write to stderr?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is not possible to redirect `echo`, but the same can be achieved by using `writeLine` on the `stderr` handle (no special imports required):

```nim
stderr.writeLine("Error: ", 42)
```

Documentation links:

- [`writeLine` in `streams` module](https://nim-lang.org/docs/streams.html#writeLn,Stream,varargs[string,])
- [`stderr` in `system` module](https://nim-lang.org/docs/system.html#stderr)

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to call [`writeLine`](https://nim-lang.org/docs/io.html#writeLine%2CFile%2Cvarargs%5BTy%2C%5D). It is listed among the [`system` Exports](https://nim-lang.org/docs/system.html#19). The docs for [`echo`](https://nim-lang.org/docs/system.html#echo%2Cvarargs%5Btyped%2C%5D) suggest also calling [`flushFile`](https://nim-lang.org/docs/io.html#flushFile,File) as below.

```
writeLine(stderr, "my err")
flushFile(stderr)
```

This was tested with Nim 1.4.2.